# many to many relationship using objectify?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I am moving my application from a relational DB to objectify / google app engine.

The application has a relationship which is modelled as follows:

One `Message` can be sent to many `Users`.  Each `User` can have many `Message`s addressed to them.

I need to be able to scan for all `Message`s addressed to a particular `User`.

How do I do this with Objectify?

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of ways to do it.

1. You can save a list of messages in the user object. This will work nicely with your requirement to get all messages addressed to a user, as there is no need to do a query.
2. You can save a list of users in the message object. To get all the messages addressed to a single user, do a query.
3. you can save BOTH lists above. Remember, in App Engine there is usually no need to normalize and worry about disk space and duplicates. Almost always build your structure so that queries will be fast.
4. You can forget about lists, and have Relationship objects just like a table in a relational database. It can still be the decent options in App Engine in some use cases, for example when the lists are just too big (thousands) and will bloat your objects and may not even be query-able.

The most important variable that will determine which approach to take in relation to the query you specified, is how many messages will usually be addressed to a single user, and will there be a maximum number of messages? If we are talking about average of dozens or less and maximum of hundreds, a list of messages in the user object sounds to me like a good option. If we are talking about more, and especially if unlimited, it won't work so well, and you will need to make an actual query.

Comment: +1, the key here is to change the perception of the `Message` : In RDBMS you would treat your message as an absolute "piece of information" that you connect to users through a query. With the datastore, Users own a copy of a message, like an email : with your Gmail account, you don't care if the sender removes the email after sending it, once you receive the email you actually "own" a copy that is disconnected from the sender. To "send" a `Message` you must actually put a copy in both the sender "sent" basket, and in the recipients "inbox" basket.

Answer (score 3):

Beyond the answers already posted I would suggest that you **not** include a link from User to the Message, for three reasons:

- Collections in GAE are hard limited to 5000 items. As soon as your user's inbox exceeds 5k items your app will start throwing exceptions.
- There is a performance cost to expanding the quantity of data in an entity; loading a bunch of 500k entities is slower than loading a bunch of 5k entities. Plus your usage of memcache will be less effective since you can fit fewer items in the same space. User objects tend to get loaded a *lot*.
- You can easily hit the transaction rate limit for a single entity (1/s). If 50 people send you a message at the same time, you will have massive concurrency problems as all 50 retry with optimistic failures.

If you can live with a limit of 5000 recipients for a single message, storing the Set of destination keys in the Message (and indexing this set so you can query for all messages of a user) is probably a great solution. There is almost certainly an advantage also to assigning the message a @Parent of the sender.

If you are twitter-like and expect a message to have more than 5k recipients, or if your messages typically have a lot of recipients (thus the message entity is bloated), you may wish to consider the Relation Index Entity pattern that Brett Slatkin talked about in his Google I/O talk from 2009: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AgaL6NGpkB8

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I expect less than 5000 recipients per message.  But how can I have the message be the parent of the sender?  Don't you mean the other way around?  Since once someone has created a message, it will always be from them and can't be 'from' anybody else.

Comment: It seems that, if the items exceed 5000, create another entity to store the relation is the best solution (which is like the relationship database map table)

Answer (score 1):

You have to maintain the relationship on your own. This is because depending on the application it would make sense to let the users exist without messages, or even the opposite.

The suggested approach by Objectify Wiki (https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify Multi-Value Relationship) is to keep a collection(or array) of keys

```
public class Message
{
    @Id String timeStamp;
    Key<User>[] destination;
}

public class User
{
    @Id String name;
    Key<Message>[] inbox;
}
```

Then if you want to remove all user messages when the user is removed, just remove them from the datastore before the user. Also is exactly the same if you want to add a new message for a particular user.